# CIImageProcessorKernel sample codes return all-white result

Tags: swift, xcode, ios11, ciimage

I tried binarizing the image captured by the phone camera with the sample codes at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/ciimageprocessorkernel, that is:

First subclassing `CIImageProcessorKernel` as:

```
class ThresholdImageProcessorKernel: CIImageProcessorKernel {
    static let device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()        
    override class func process(with inputs: [CIImageProcessorInput]?, arguments: [String : Any]?, output: CIImageProcessorOutput) throws {                
        guard            
            let device = device,            
            let commandBuffer = output.metalCommandBuffer,            
            let input = inputs?.first,            
            let sourceTexture = input.metalTexture,            
            let destinationTexture = output.metalTexture,            
            let thresholdValue = arguments?["thresholdValue"] as? Float else  {                
                return        
            }                

        let threshold = MPSImageThresholdBinary(
                device: device,                                                
                thresholdValue: thresholdValue,                                               
                maximumValue: 1.0,                                                
                linearGrayColorTransform: nil)                

        threshold.encode(
            commandBuffer: commandBuffer,                         
            sourceTexture: sourceTexture,                         
            destinationTexture: destinationTexture)    
    }
}
```

Then use it as (there is a typo in the Developer page missing an **r** at `ThresholdImageProcessorKernel`):

```
    let result = try? ThresholdImageProcessorKernel.apply( 
        withExtent: inputImage.extent,            
        inputs: [inputImage],            
        arguments: ["thresholdValue": 0.25])
```

The result is an all-white image??

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to override `outputFormat` and `formatForInput`. For example:

```
override class var outputFormat: CIFormat {
    return kCIFormatBGRA8
}
override class func formatForInput(at input: Int32) -> CIFormat {
    return kCIFormatBGRA8
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

1. Test on a real device.
2. Adjust the threshold value.
3. Make sure that both of the device's cameras are pointing at some object (for example, *not* the table) to figure out which one is being used.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error recently and the problem is this line:

`let thresholdValue = arguments?["thresholdValue"] as? Float`

which fails in newer Swift versions because `arguments?["thresholdValue"]` contains a `Double` and trying to cast it to `Float` will fail at this point. Change the line to

`let thresholdValue = arguments?["thresholdValue"] as? Double`

and in the initializer of `MPSImageThresholdBinary` make a float out of it again.

`thresholdValue: Float(thresholdValue)`